# How to add loader correctly while infinite scrolling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll

I tried multiple ways to implement loading while fetching more data during infinite scrolling, but nothing worked properly, so I deleted loader; I have here state (with redux) named: loading but cannot write the logic of loading correctly. Could you please tell me how I can make it work?
Here I will provide with code:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {setAllUsers, setLoading, setPage} from '../redux/actions/actions';
import User from './User';
import '../styles/AllUsersList.css';

const AllUsersList = () => {
    const allUsers = useSelector(state => state.setAllUsersReducer);
    const page = useSelector(state => state.setPageReducer);
    const loading = useSelector(state => state.setLoadingReducer);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
  

    const fetchAllUsers = () => {
       fetch(`${url}/${page}/15`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                dispatch(setAllUsers(data.list));
            })
            .catch(err => console.log('Error message: ', err))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      fetchAllUsers();
    }, [page])

    const handleScroll = () => {
        dispatch(setPage());
    }

    window.onscroll = function () {
        if(window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop === document.documentElement.offsetHeight) {
            handleScroll();
        }
    }


    return (
        <div className="allUsersList">
            {
                allUsers ? (
                    allUsers.map((user, index) => (
                        <Link key={user.id} to={`/user/${user.id}`}>
                            <User name={user.name} lastName={user.lastName} prefix={user.prefix} title={user.title} img={user.imageUrl}/>
                        </Link>
                    ))
                ) : (
                    <div> Loading... </div>
                )
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default AllUsersList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your state `loading` would be set to `true` in your function `fetchAllUsers` the data and when the promise resolves it gets set to `false`.

Here's an example on how you would do it, you can adapt it to use a redux dispatcher to change loading state.

```js
const loading = useState(false);

...

const fetchAllUsers = () => {
       setLoading(true);
       fetch(`${url}/${page}/15`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                dispatch(setAllUsers(data.list));
            })
            .catch(err => console.log('Error message: ', err))
            .finally(() => {
                setLoading(false);
             })
    }

...

{
                !loading ? (
                    allUsers.map((user, index) => (
                        <Link key={user.id} to={`/user/${user.id}`}>
                            <User name={user.name} lastName={user.lastName} prefix={user.prefix} title={user.title} img={user.imageUrl}/>
                        </Link>
                    ))
                ) : (
                    <div> Loading... </div>
                )
            }
```